# Find by category name or make extra table

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database where I have a list of website addresses, each one with a category.
The among the table fields I have `site_id, site_url and site_category`. In `site_category` I have the categories in plain english, like: movies, tutorials, etc...

I want to know what is better for speed. To have it like that or to have two tables:

Websites : `site_id, site_url and site_category` .

Categories: `category_id, category_name`

And in the `site_category` for the "websites" table only put the `category_id`.

I am making a directory with PHP and want to know, at the moment of wanting to query, what is better. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As with almost everything SQL, it really depends on a whole bunch of factors.

In general, a query against a single table is likely going to perform better than a query against two tables.

---

With relatively short values for "category_name" (say 8 characters or less), and with an appropriate index category_name as a leading column, you'll get good performance of queries like:

```
SELECT * FROM websites WHERE category_name = 'movies' ORDER BY category
```

---

For optimum performance, consider an `ENUM` columns for category_name.  But this would mean that the values for `category_name` would be "fixed" as part of the column definition.

If you need to get a list of distinct category_name values (for a drop down list box, for example), then a separate table (such as Categories table in your example) is going to be preferred.

The big question is whether a "category" is an entity in your system.  That is, is a "category" a person, place, thing, concept or event, which is important to the business, can be uniquely identified, and which you need to store information about.

If so, it's an "entity", and you want to create a separate table for it.

---

A bigger question for you to consider is the relationship between a website and a category.  Can a website have more than one category?

If so, then you'll need to think in terms of a relationship table, which relates websites and categories. For example:

```
 website_category (website_id, category_id)
```

It's critical that the "entities" and "relationships" between the entities are represented appropriately in your database design. Make sure you get that right first, before you tweak to optimize performance.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to pre-optimize your site at the expense of a good [normalized](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) DB design. My advice: Setup two different tables. One for categories. The other for websites. Then link the two via a category ID. That way, if you ever need to update a category's name, you won't have to update multiple rows inside the websites table.

Answer (score 0):

Your second method is more robust. If you ever wanted to change the name of a category, you'd only need to change once.

Also, it gives you more flexibility in the case where you want to have multiple categories on a website.